# I am trying to use sprites for a webpage but I don't know how to work with images being double resolution

Tags: css, background-image, css-sprites, retina

I am trying to use sprites for a webpage but I don't know how to work with images being double resolution. Can you pls help?

So far I am using:

```
.div {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px; ---> they remain 400px;
    height: 200px; ---> they remain 400px;
    background: url(Sprite.png) 10px 0;
}
```

The problem is that images still show too big. Not sure how to scale them down.

Thanks

Comment: Add `background-size` and set it to half the original resolution.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the size of the background images by using the `background-size` property as shown in the example at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background-size.